# null values when i change of form

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, null

Im using jsp and ajax to get data from my db and post it in a table. At the moment i'm be able to get data using any field, the problem is when i want to use 2 or more fields i get null values when i click another field

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
        title: 'Cliente',
        toolbarsearch: true,
        paging: true, //Enable paging
        pageSize: 10, //Set page size (default: 10)
        sorting: true, //Enable sorting
        defaultSorting: 'nombre_cliente ASC',
        actions: {
            listAction: 'CRUDController?action=list',
            createAction:'CRUDController?action=create',
            updateAction: 'CRUDController?action=update',
            deleteAction: 'CRUDController?action=delete'
        },
        fields: {
            nombre_cliente: {
                title: 'Nombre',
                key: true,
                list: true,
                create:true
            },
            rut: {
                title: 'R.U.T',
                width: '30%',
                edit:true
            },

            direccion: {
                title: 'Direccion',
                width: '20%',
                edit: true
            },
            comuna: {
                title: 'Comuna',
                width: '20%',
                edit: true
            },
            ciudad: {
                title: 'Ciudad',
                width: '20%',
                edit: true
            },
            region: {
                title: 'Region',
                width: '20%',
                edit: true
            },
            correo: {
                title: 'Email',
                width: '20%',
                edit: true
            },
            telefono: {
                title: 'Telefono',
                width: '20%',
                edit: true
            }
        }
    });
     $('#PersonTableContainer').keyup(function(e){

     $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable('load', {
         searchNombre: $('#jtable-toolbarsearch-nombre_cliente').val(),
         searchRut: $('#jtable-toolbarsearch-rut').val(),
         searchDireccion: $('#jtable-toolbarsearch-direccion').val(),
         searchComuna: $('#jtable-toolbarsearch-comuna').val(),
         searchCiudad: $('#jtable-toolbarsearch-ciudad').val(),
         searchRegion: $('#jtable-toolbarsearch-region').val(),
         searchCorreo: $('#jtable-toolbarsearch-correo').val(),
         searchTelefono: $('#jtable-toolbarsearch-telefono').val(),
        }); 
    });
    $('#PersonTableContainer').keyup();
});
```

here is my controller

```
    if(request.getParameter("action")!=null){
        List<BeanCliente> lstUser=new ArrayList<BeanCliente>();
        String action=(String)request.getParameter("action");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        response.setContentType("application/json");

        if(action.equals("list")){
            try
            {                       
                //Fetch Data from User Table
                int startPageIndex=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("jtStartIndex"));
                int numRecordsPerPage=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("jtPageSize"));
                String sorting = request.getParameter("jtSorting");
                String searchNombre = request.getParameter("searchNombre");
                String searchRut = request.getParameter("searchRut");
                String searchDireccion = request.getParameter("searchDireccion");
                String searchComuna = request.getParameter("searchComuna");
                String searchCiudad = request.getParameter("searchCiudad");
                String searchRegion = request.getParameter("searchRegion");
                String searchCorreo = request.getParameter("searchCorreo");
                String searchTelefono = request.getParameter("searchTelefono");
                  System.out.println(sorting+searchNombre+searchRut+searchDireccion+searchComuna+searchCiudad+searchRegion+searchCorreo+searchTelefono);
                lstUser=dao.getAllUsers(searchNombre,searchRut,searchDireccion,searchComuna,searchCiudad,searchRegion,searchCorreo,searchTelefono,startPageIndex,numRecordsPerPage,sorting );
                int userCount=dao.getUserCount();       
                JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(lstUser, new TypeToken<List<BeanCliente>>() {}.getType());
                JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
                String listData=jsonArray.toString();               
                listData="      {\"Result\":\"OK\",\"Records\":"+listData+",\"TotalRecordCount\":"+userCount+"}";           
                response.getWriter().print(listData);

                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    String error="{\"Result\":\"ERROR\",\"Message\":"+ex.getMessage()+"}";
                    response.getWriter().print(error);
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }   
        }
```

im using this jquery to add input fields

```
 /** JTABLE Multiple toolbar search extension 

 **/
(function ($) {
var base={
    _addRowToTableHead:$.hik.jtable.prototype._addRowToTableHead
}
$.extend(true, $.hik.jtable.prototype, {
    options: {
        toolbarsearch:false
    },
    /** Overrides Method
    /* Adds tr element to given thead element
    *************************************************************************/
    _addRowToTableHead: function ($thead) {
        var $tr = $('<tr></tr>')
            .appendTo($thead);

        this._addColumnsToHeaderRow($tr);
        if(this.options.toolbarsearch){         
            var $tr = $('<tr></tr>')
            .appendTo($thead);
            this._toolbarsearch_addColumnsToHeaderRow($tr);
        }

    },
    /* Adds column header cells to given tr element.
    *************************************************************************/
    _toolbarsearch_addColumnsToHeaderRow: function ($tr) {
        var self = this;
        for (var i = 0; i < this._columnList.length; i++) {
            var fieldName = this._columnList[i];
            var $headerCell = this._toolbarsearch_createHeaderCellForField(fieldName, this.options.fields[fieldName]);
            $headerCell.appendTo($tr);
        }
        $reset = $('<th></th>')
            .addClass('jtable-toolbarsearch-reset')
            .attr('colspan',$(".jtable-command-column-header").length);
        $resetbutton = $('<input type="button" value="Buscar"/>').appendTo($reset);
        $resetbutton.click(function(){
            $('.jtable-toolbarsearch').val('');
            self.load({});              
        });
        $tr.append($reset);
    },      

    /* Creates a header cell for given field.
    *  Returns th jQuery object.
    *************************************************************************/      
    _toolbarsearch_createHeaderCellForField: function (fieldName, field) {
        var self = this;
        if(typeof field.searchable === 'undefined'){
            field.searchable = true;
        };
        field.width = field.width || '10%'; //default column width: 10%.
        var $input = this._getColumnDisplay(fieldName,field);

        $input.bind('change',function(){
            var $q=[];
            var $opt=[];
            var $postData={};
            var $i =0;
                $('.jtable-toolbarsearch').each(function(){
                    var $id = $(this).attr('id');
                    if($(this).val().length>=1){
                        $opt.push($id.replace('jtable-toolbarsearch-',''));                              
                        $q.push($(this).val());
                        $i++;
                    }
                });
            self.load({'q[]':$q,'opt[]':$opt});
        });

        var $headerContainerDiv = $('<div />')
            .addClass('jtable-column-header-container');

        if(field.searchable){   
            $headerContainerDiv.append($input);
        }
        var $th = $('<th></th>')
            .addClass('jtable-column-header')
            .css('width', field.width)
            .data('fieldName', fieldName)
            .append($headerContainerDiv);
        return $th;     

    },
    _getColumnDisplay:function(fieldName,field){
        if (field.type == 'date') {
            return this._getDisplayDate(fieldName,field);
        } else if (field.type == 'checkbox') {
            return this._getDisplayCheckBox(fieldName,field);
        } else if (field.options) { //combobox or radio button list since there are options.
            return this._getDisplayComboBox(fieldName,field);
        } else {
            return this._getDisplayText(fieldName,field);
        }
    },
    _getDisplayDate:function(fieldName,field){
        var displayFormat = field.displayFormat || this.options.defaultDateFormat;
        var $input = $('<input id="jtable-toolbarsearch-' + fieldName + '" type="text"/>')
        .addClass('jtable-toolbarsearch')
        .css('width','90%')
        .datepicker({dateFormat:displayFormat});
        return $input;
    },
    _getDisplayText:function(fieldName,field){
        var $input = $('<input id="jtable-toolbarsearch-' + fieldName + '" type="text"/>')
        .addClass('jtable-toolbarsearch')
        .css('width','90%');
        return $input;
    },
    _getDisplayCheckBox:function(fieldName,field){
        var $input = $('<input id="jtable-toolbarsearch-' + fieldName + '" type="text"/>')
        .addClass('jtable-toolbarsearch')
        .css('width','90%')
        return $input;
    },
    _getDisplayComboBox:function(fieldName,field){

        var $input = $('<select id="jtable-toolbarsearch-' + fieldName + '"></select>')
        .addClass('jtable-toolbarsearch')
        .css('width','90%')
        for (var option in field.options) {
            console.log(field.options[option]);
            $input.append('<option value="' + option + '">' + field.options[option] + '</option>');
        }
        return $input;
    }


});

 })(jQuery);
```

to make more clear 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubUx9.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVe84.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing from jquery toolbar fixed the problem.

```
    $input.bind('change',function(){
        var $q=[];
        var $opt=[];
        var $postData={};
        var $i =0;
            $('.jtable-toolbarsearch').each(function(){
                var $id = $(this).attr('id');
                if($(this).val().length>=1){
                    $opt.push($id.replace('jtable-toolbarsearch-',''));                              
                    $q.push($(this).val());
                    $i++;
                }
            });
        self.load({'q[]':$q,'opt[]':$opt});
    });
```